# Error on creating dynamic FormControl in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Error on creating dynamic FormControl in Angular, console throws following error:

> ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

for following angular component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "app-dynamic-form",
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <div *ngFor="let prop of personProps">
        <input type="text" [formControlName]="prop">
      </div>
    </form>
    <pre>{{form.value | json }}</pre>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  person: {
    firstname: "Hozefa";
    age: 23;
  };
  personProps = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const formDataObj = {};
    for (const prop of Object.keys(this.person)) {
      formDataObj[prop] = new FormControl(this.person[prop]);
      this.personProps.push(prop);
    }

    this.form = new FormGroup(formDataObj);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> person: {
>     firstname: "Hozefa";
>     age: 23;
>   };
> ```

Object definition is wrong, replace to:

```
person = {
    firstname: "Hozefa",
    age: 23
  };
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-item-in-dynamic-reactive-form-in-angular-qfmcg4)

Comment: Thanks a lot ...  noob mistake